# the triangle cosine relation in a complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

I have a triangle $ABC$ in a complex plane. The arrangement of vertices is in a counterclockwise direction. The coordinates of $A$,$B$,$C$ are $z_A$,$z_B$,$z_C$ respectively.
It is given that length of side $AB = c, AC = b$ and $\angle BAC = \alpha$. I need to find the other sides and angles of the triangle. How do i do this with complex numbers?

I know with trigonometry using the sine and cosine rules, all the length and angles can be derived. but how to get it using complex numbers?

Comment: my main issue is applying the cosine rule to get the third side. Whats its complex equivalent?

Comment: What about $z_B-z_C$?

Comment: not given, but two sides and the angle in between is known, so the remaining angles and sides can be uniquely determined, at least using trigonometry i know how to find this.

Comment: You need $|z_B-z_C|^2=(z_B-z_C)\overline{(z_B-z_C)}$ and $z_B-z_C=(z_B-z_A)+(z_A-z_C)$. You know that $|z_B-z_A|^2=c^2$ and $|z_C-z_A|^2=b^2$...

Comment: we also know  $\angle BAC = \alpha$

Comment: Sure. You will need it to find the product $(z_B-z_A)(z_A-z_C)$.

Comment: can you explain me how to use it. So far I am using $(z_1-z_2)e^{i\alpha} = \frac{c}{b}(z_1-z_3)$. But then how to now find the third side and other two angles?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the connection with the law of cosines. You can see which quantities correspond to which.

You have $z_B-z_A=ce^{i\alpha_1}$ and $z_C-z_A=be^{i\alpha_2}$, hence $z_A-z_C=be^{i(\alpha_2+\pi)}$. Clearly $\alpha_2-\alpha_1=\alpha$. Then
$z_B-z_C=(z_B-z_A)+(z_A-z_C)$ and
$$
a^2=|z_B-z_C|^2=(z_B-z_C)\overline{(z_B-z_C)}=(z_B-z_A)\overline{(z_B-z_A)}+(z_A-z_C)\overline{(z_A-z_C)}+2Re[(z_B-z_A)\overline{(z_A-z_C)}]=
$$ 
$$
=c^2+b^2+2bcRe(e^{i(\alpha_1-\alpha_2-\pi)})=c^2+b^2-2bc\cos\alpha
$$

Comment: well i know i can write it using only the real parts. but i want to write it in a purely complex form.

Comment: You can replace the term with the real part by $(z_B-z_A)\overline{(z_A-z_C)}+\overline{(z_B-z_A)}(z_A-z_C)$

Comment: Is this purely complex for you?

Comment: with modulus , i have to take the square root. I want to avoid sauqre roos and convert to the form with has $e^{i\alpha}$ in it. Then taking the square root will only be dividing the angle in exponential by 2. And i guess it will also look much nicer.